# How to create generic cucumber step which accepts an argument and verifies page heading of the pageobjects

Tags: java, spring, cucumber

I would like to verify subsequent pages after my cucumber test clicks on the links that lead to different pages.

I would like to do verification of the links on a webpage. My Cucumber test is parsing all links and navigates to each of them. I want to create a generic cucumber step that will accept some argument by which I will verify that the correct page is opened.

So far I created a generic cucumber step that accepts page heading string by which I verify if navigation leads to the correct page.

My Cucumber test:

```
Scenario Outline: As a not registered User I can visit "<page>"
    When user looks at the webpage
    And user clicks on "<link>" 
    Then user is navigated to "<page>"
    Examples:
      | link                                | page                                                               
      | How to register                     | Registration page                                
      | Questions & Answers                 | Login FAQ's                                    
      | Register Now                        | Create account 
      | Forgot your name or password?       | Reset Password
```

My Step looks like this:

```
@Then("^user is navigated to \"([^\"]*)\"$")
    public void userIsNavigatedTo(final String pageHeading) throws IOException {
        switch (pageHeading) {
            case "Registration page":
                Assert.assertTrue(
                        howToRegisterPage.getPageHeading().getText()
                                .equalsIgnoreCase(pageHeading)
                );
                break;
            case "Login FAQ's":
                Assert.assertTrue(
                    questionsAndAnswersPage.getPageHeading().getText()
                            .equalsIgnoreCase(pageHeading)
                );
                break;
   //.....//
}
```

This switch is looking awful to me, moreover, I understand that soon it will be too long to read and too difficult to maintain.

P.S. All my PageObjects are Spring Beans and can be autowired into StepDefinition class, but I have no idea how I can make my "userIsNavigatedTo"
generic, what I need to pass as an argument and how I can take correct PageObject for every iteration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid switch-case you can create a `Map<String, YourPageObject>` that maps page heading to your page object.

```
public class StepDefinition{
  private final Map<String, YourPageObject> pageObjectsIndex;

  @Autowired
  public StepDefinition(List<YourPageObject> yourPageObjects){
    pageObjectsIndex = yourPageObjects.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(page -> page.getPageHeading().getText().toUpper(), Function.identity());
  }

  @Then("^user is navigated to \"([^\"]*)\"$")
   public void userIsNavigatedTo(final String pageHeading) throws IOException {
     Assert.assertTrue(pageObjectsIndex.get(pageHeading.toUpper()).isLoaded());
   }
}
```

The side-effect of these idea is that each page needs to have its own class that implements YourPageObject interface. I wrote "side-effect" because I'm not sure if it is a drawback or an advantage (probably it is case dependent ;) ).

Comment: Thank you! That's something that I was looking for. Although I can't map pageObjectsIndex in the constructor of the StepDefinition, since when you call
page -> page.getPageHeading(), NoSuchElementException is thrown, because the driver did not yet open that page to grab the heading.

It opens the page only when the thread is inside the userIsNavigatedTo(final String pageHeading) method.

Comment: @pa Hmm, it is posible to defer call to getPageHeading(). E.g. you can add a name for a page and use it instead of pageHeading in scenario. You can even use enums for this.

Comment: Yes, I added a page name and in the scenario, I filter the page by page name and then verify that page heading element.
Thank you, again!

Answer (score 0):

Since it looks like you're using page objects, I would recommend writing a method in each page object class to check to see if an element is there.  Mine is a bit more complex than what I'll show below because I wrap my page object methods to deal with exception handling, but a basic example might be:

```
@FindBy(xpath = "//h1[.='Page Header']"
WebElement pageHeader;

public boolean isLoaded() {
    return pageHeader.isDisplayed();
}
```

You'd still do a switch/case in your step, but it would read easier, and you could assert the page object method directly:

```
Assert.assertTrue(myPage.isLoaded());
```

Comment: Yes, I have that thought in mind, but I still want to get rid of switch altogether, that's why I called this method generic in the subject.
To put it simply, I want to pass a PageObject class name to my step method as an argument and inside that method, I would call spring bean by class name.
I just have no idea how to do it :)
Maybe it is not the best solution, so I am open to any better idea.

Answer (score 0):

I would argue that you are wasting alot of time for a test that provides little value is very fragile, and is using the wrong assertion to prove its validity

**First of all the lack of value:**

The only value your test has is that you can navigate to the particular page. Whilst this might have some relevance to the page you are navigating from, its quite an expensive test to prove you have the correct link on a page. Generally navigation is either

- a poor substitute for behaviour, i.e. the ability to go to the other page is really part of some specific functionality of starting page. So you would be better to prove the navigation implicitely by working through that functionality
- something that isn't page specific i.e. a menu that is shared on many pages, header, footer, sidebar

**Second: Fragility**

Page titles change all the time, page purpose changes rarely. By linking navigation to the page title you are just increasing the cost of change of changing a Page Title. Now this trivial task involves modifying scenarios and dealing with complex test code.

**Third: Wrong assertion**

Rather than using the title, you would be better served using an id to identify a page.

Overall writing individual scenarios for each link that appears on a page will quickly result in a very unwieldy test suite. You would be much better off using a spider to test links, and focus on testing functionality, which will implicitly prove important navigation paths.